# Can PythonWin be used with Python 3.5?

Tags: python, python-3.5

My company has been using Python 2.7 for lo these many years, because all scripts we have delivered to customers run on Python 2.7, and so new customers get scripts based on the old ones, and so new customers have to get 2.7.  Right? And sometime back, just so I could have it to play with, I installed 3.2 on my computer.

Well, we have a new customer and enough time that we can use him as an opportunity to attempt to move into the twentieth century.  (Note that I did not say twenty-first.  That would be too much to ask.)  So, I downloaded and installed the latest version of Python, 3.5.1, on my computer.

We have always used the PythonWin GUI editor.  I installed the latest version of that into my 3.2 installation a few days ago, with no problem.  I wanted to install it for 3.5.1, but the installer claimed that it required 3.2, which it could no longer find.  It seems the 3.2 version, which was created in 2011, is the newest version.

Is the PythonWin editor considered obsolete?  I recently found the PyCharm editor, and it looks very good, but I'd like to have the well-known PythonWin editor available also.

Comment: There are some comments on the SourceForge page for pywin32 about having to mess with the registry: http://sourceforge.net/p/pywin32/activity?page=0&limit=100. (But PyCharm is incredible and you should strongly consider switching to it if budget permits.)

Comment: Get the correct installer from https://sourceforge.net/projects/pywin32/files/pywin32/Build%20220/

Answer (score 0):

I'd forgotten about this: https://winpython.github.io/. It includes winpython.